# intellij IDEA refactoring: extract method: reverse possible

Tags: intellij-idea

With intellij IDEA: I can extract code into a method.

Anyhow, I need the reverse action:

I have a method and want to have the code of this method back in the caller environment/method.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The refactor option you're looking for is "Inline...". It's right below "Extract" in the refactor menu.

Comment: This is the solution. 

keyboard shortcut: shift-alt-i